# error when running as script, fine from REPL

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia and try to convert some of my Python codebase.

I wrote a spatial interpolation algorithm and try to run it as a script from the console.
`juliatest.jl` is the main file calling functions from another script `PCTools.jl`.
I added `include("PCTools.jl")` at the top.

Running `julia juliatest.jl` leads to this error message:

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: k > number of points in tree or < 0
Stacktrace:
 [1] check_k
   @ ~/.julia/packages/NearestNeighbors/8gDgr/src/knn.jl:3 [inlined]
 [2] knn(tree::KDTree{SVector{2, Float64}, Euclidean, Float64}, points::Vector{SVector{2, Int64}}, k::Int64, sortres::Bool, skip::typeof(NearestNeighbors.always_false))
   @ NearestNeighbors ~/.julia/packages/NearestNeighbors/8gDgr/src/knn.jl:19
 [3] knn(tree::KDTree{SVector{2, Float64}, Euclidean, Float64}, point::Matrix{Int64}, k::Int64, sortres::Bool, skip::typeof(NearestNeighbors.always_false))
   @ NearestNeighbors ~/.julia/packages/NearestNeighbors/8gDgr/src/knn.jl:63
 [4] _nn
   @ ~/.julia/packages/NearestNeighbors/8gDgr/src/knn.jl:70 [inlined]
 [5] nn (repeats 2 times)
   @ ~/.julia/packages/NearestNeighbors/8gDgr/src/knn.jl:68 [inlined]
 [6] InterpolateGrid(raster::Matrix{Float64}, max_dist::Int64, res::Float64)
   @ Main ~/repos/julia/PCtools.jl:131
 [7] top-level scope
   @ ~/repos/julia/juliatests.jl:14
```

Interestingly, if I run the steps from `juliatest.jl` and call `InterpolateGrid` from `PCtools.jl` step-by-step from the REPL, it works without a problem.

I think Julia trips up at this part of the code (inside `InterpolateGrid`):

```
rows, cols = collect(vec(gridy')), collect(vec(gridx'))
gridxy = collect(hcat(rows, cols)')
xy = convert(Array{Float64, 2}, collect(hcat(x, y)'))

kdtree = KDTree(xy)
indices, distances = nn(kdtree, gridxy)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This looks like a variable scoping issue. basically you should avoid global variables in your code and have everything in functions. Scoping works sometimes slightly different depending whether you run the code from file or REPL. Have a look at https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/

Comment: Thanks, I will read through it. All the variables in the snippet are only created and used inside the `InterpolateGrid` function.